# Can (should?) Stack expand its size to its positioned children?

Tags: flutter

I have a `Stack` widget that contains two `Image` widgets, one image overlaying the other.  One image has top set to 10 so it sits 10 pixels higher on the screen.  Unfortunately the 10.0px gets cut off at the bottom of the screen.  If I set an `overflow.visible` then I can see it.

I wrap the stack with a `GestureDetector` the 10.0px overflow is not inside the `GestureDetector` so when a user clicks on the bottom of the image, nothing happens.  The images will be different sizes so I can't set a definite height.

Is there a way to increase the size of the `GestureDector` to the size of its children?

```
return new GestureDetector(
  onTapDown: (x) => print('onTapDown'),
  child: new Stack(
    overflow: Overflow.visible,
    children: [
      new Positioned(
        child: shadowImage,
        top: 10.0,
      ),
      new Positioned(
        child: initialImage,
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can (should?) Stack expand its size to its positioned children?

No. But if you want the following, then your child should *not* be positionned. 
`Stack`, if it has one, will size itself around the first non-positionned child.

So you could transform your `shadowImage` to

```
children: [
  new Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
    child: shadowImage
  ),
  new Positioned(
    child: initialImage,
  ),
],
```

Comment: That is wonderful :-)  Sizing around the first non-positioned child is the detail I was after.  Thank you!

Comment: This detail is also the reason for the `align` field. Where when you have more then one non-positionned child, you can align the others based on the first one.